# PhoneGap plugin YouTube Intent back button

Tags: cordova, youtube-api, phonegap-plugins

I use the following code to start a YouTubeStandalonePlayer Intent from my Phonegap / Cordova plugin:

```
package com.remcob00.plugins.youtube;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

import org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeStandalonePlayer;

public class YouTube extends Plugin {

@Override
public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId) {
    try {
        JSONObject jo = args.getJSONObject(0);
        doSendIntent(jo.getString("videoid")); 
        return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION);
    }
}

private void doSendIntent(String videoid) {
    // API key instructions https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/register
    Intent youtubeIntent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent((Activity) this.cordova, "YOUR_API_KEY", videoid);
    this.cordova.startActivityForResult(this, youtubeIntent, 0);
}

}
```

([The plugin on GitHub](https://github.com/remcob00/cordova-phonegap_youtube_player_api_android))

But the problem is that if I open the YouTube Intent and I press the back button I, it does't go back to the page from where I opened the intent but the index.html file. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a problem in the Android Emulator. I have tested it on a real device and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find any better solution, you could store your current location using window.localStorage after each page change and then when the index.html is opened, detect Resume event and check if the value of window.localStorage isn't empty.

If it isn't - simply redirect to that location.